# Why cant I remove an image after pushing it to hub?

Tags: docker

I have built an image, tagged it and published it to docker registry. Now I am trying to remove the image from my host but its failing with below error:

command using : `docker rmi 4118144272e8`

error :

```
Error response from daemon: conflict: unable to delete 4118144272e8 (must 
be forced) - image is referenced in multiple repositories
```

While trying to remove using name instead of id different error coming:

error :

```
Error response from daemon: No such image: reminder/psscript:latest
```

But my image has the tag v1 not latest.

Comment: I think the second answer here will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32944391/how-to-remove-multiple-docker-images-with-the-same-imageid

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove multiple docker images with the same imageID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32944391/how-to-remove-multiple-docker-images-with-the-same-imageid)

Comment: If it has the tag `v1` then you need to `docker rmi reminder/psscript:v1`.  It will also have some other name:tag and you need to `docker rmi` the other name:tag as well.